# SQL command to print .SQL filename

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, sqlcl

Is there any SQL command to print the name of the .SQL file that is currently being executed in the sqlplus prompt?

There's is a Unix way to do it. But I am looking for a valid SQL command that displays the current filename.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not a proper command to do this but great ( and obvious ) ER for [sqlcl](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/sqlcl.html)

There's a couple ways to achieve this today. The first is to add code into every script to use `dbms_application_info` and set the module/action to the name of the process and script. This will work with any tool as it's putting the info into the db for retrieval later via sql/plsql. It could also be handy as this is captured into things like ASH/AWR/v$session.

There's another sqlcl specific way which is the `script` command to get access to the context running and print it. Here's an example of both options>>

```
SQL> !cat k.sql
--- generic 
exec DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_MODULE('InstallScript','k.sql');


select   sys_context('USERENV', 'ACTION'), sys_context('USERENV', 'MODULE') from dual;

-- sqlcl specific.....
script
ctx.write(ctx.getLastUrl() + "\n");
/

SQL> @k.sql

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

   SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','ACTION')    SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','MODULE')
__________________________________ __________________________________
k.sql                              InstallScript


file:/Users/klrice/k.sql
SQL>
```